# How to Run All selenium tests without Closing Browser using junit

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have two testcases-"Signup.java", "Login.java".

Login.java

```
    public class Login extends BaseTest{

 @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "www.xyz.com";
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  @Test
  public void testLogin() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    WebElement username=driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    username.sendKeys(user);
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(pwd);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/div/button")).click();
  }

 @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
```

SignUp.java

```
public class SignUp extends BaseTest{
      private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;
      private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();


 @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "www.xyz.com";
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }


 @Test
 public void testSignUp() throws Exception {
     driver.get(baseUrl+"/");
     driver.findElement(By.id("firstname")).sendKeys("test");
     driver.findElement(By.id("lastname")).sendKeys("test");
     driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("test");
     driver.findElement(By.id("confirmPassword")).sendKeys("test");
     driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
     driver.findElement(By.name("accepted_tandc")).click(); 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Submit')]")).click();      
    }


 @After
 public void tearDown() throws Exception {
   driver.quit();
   String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
   if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
     fail(verificationErrorString);
   }
 }
}
```

BaseTest.java

```
public abstract class BaseTest {
    protected String user="xyz@gmail.com";
    protected String pwd="123";
    public static String  baseUrl;
    protected static WebDriver driver;
    private static StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @BeforeClass
        public static void setUp() throws Exception {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseUrl = "www.xyz.com";
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }

    @AfterClass
        public static void  tearDown() throws Exception {
            driver.quit();
            String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
            if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
            }
    }
}
```

Have a test Suite named AllTests.java

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({SignUp.class,Login.class,})
public class AllTests {

}
```

Now When I run AllTests.java First it will open browser and run first testcase then close the browser.then open browser to execute second testcase.

My Question is When I run test suite the browser need to close after executing all the tests.No need to open/close browser for all testcases.First open the browser and execute signup and then execute login then close.this is the procedure I need.

thanks.

Comment: Why you using `driver.quit();` in all classes , use it only in last class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BeforeSuite` and `AfterSuite` to open drivers and close drivers respectively. And in `BeforeClass` check if the driver instance is initialized or not, which will be if run in a suite, if it is not, initialize it in `BeforeClass`. Put some variable which you can use to know if you are running in suite and use it to decide whether to close the browser in `Afterclass` or not. If its running in a suite dont close it otherwise close it.

Comment: You have found how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Selenide](http://selenide.org/) a wrapper for Selenium and there you never have to use driver.quit() and the browser stays open, it only closes when all my test cases have been completed.

I would suggest to remove driver.quit() from your teardown.